# How to train my own image dataset for text recognition and create the trained model for use in OCR

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I created image data set including 62992 images with 128x128px resolution that contains characters, numbers and symbols with four kinds of font styles. how do I train this dataset and create pre-trained model for my OCR, can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think your question is too broad. SO isn't a tutorial replacement. You need to show some learning effort, start to code, and then pose specifc questions related to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to train a custom OCR, I would advise studying the Tensorflow Attention OCR implementation which can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/attention_ocr).

I've used this implementation in various projects and it gave satisfactory results in converting image to text.